# AWS CodeBuild/CodePipeline user input parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I'm new to AWS and transitioning from Azure. I would like to create a pipeline in CodePipeline which asks the user for input (for example: the user needs to input a value for the variable "hello"), and uses that input to run a CodeBuild project. In Azure DevOps this was quite easy to define in the pipeline YML specification, but I can't seem to find a way to easily do this in AWS, or am I missing something?

Comment: You can use environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

AWS CodePipeline not supporting this feature currently. What you can do is, pass this parameter in your commit message (if pipeline trigger on commits to branches) or in your Git tag (if pipeline trigger on git tag push).
example:

```
commit message: my commit message [my_var]
git tag: my_var-1.0.0
```

Then in your buildspec.yml file collect the commit message or tag and check whether it contains your required parameters. If so execute the next commands otherwise exit the script.